# Getting all users with a Role in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

*I'm new to Liferay development in general, so feel free to point out if I'm going about stuff totally the wrong way.*

I'm trying to get a DynamicQuery object of all users within a certain group (I'll use this object to further filter another query I'll do against the message board). The `User` interface seems to have a `roleIds` property that I might be able to use, since I already know the `roleId` I'm interested in. But I can't find the proper way to query if `roleIds` *contains* a certain value.

Any ideas on what I want to do?

PS: I would have the exact SQL query I could ask directly, but I'd rather use Liferay's own connection pool, without needing to do some weird ext project thingy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to access liferays own objects is by using the `XXXServiceUtil` classes (e.g. `RoleServiceUtil.getUserRoles(userId)`). Thus you rarely have to deal with any SQL directly. Either the `RoleServiceUtil` or `UserServiceUtil` might have what you need.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a DynamicQuery. These are the methods you are looking for in the classes that Dirk points out:

```
long[] UserServiceUtil.getRoleUserIds(long roleId)
```

or

```
long[] UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUserIds(long roleId)
List<User> UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers(long roleId)
```

Remember that the methods in the classes XXXLocalServiceUtil are not checking the permissions of the current user.

EDIT: If you are looking for all users with a given role within a given community:

```
long companyId= _X_; //Perhaps CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId() if you don't have it anywhere else?
Role role=RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, "Example Role");
Group group=GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(companyId, "Example Community");
List<UserGroupRole> userGroupRoles = UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.
                       getUserGroupRolesByGroupAndRole(groupId, role.getRoleId());
for(UserGroupRole userGroupRole:userGroupRoles){
    User oneUser=userGroupRole.getUser();
}
```

Comment: I want to get the Users who has assigned specific Organization Roles, i got the Role id of the Role but not able to get the USers associated with that Role id. I also got that the entries are inside the USerGroupTable. Can you please help me....

Comment: You can utilize `UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers(roleId)`

Answer (score 1):

The roles of an Organizations are stored in the table UserGroupRole, so if you want to get the owner of an Organization you must use the following code:

```
boolean isOrgOwner = 
    UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserGroupRole(
        usr.getUserId(), 
        this.currentOrganization.getGroupId(), 
        RoleConstants.ORGANIZATION_OWNER);
```

If you want to retrieve all the Organization Owners of an organization:

```
List<User> administrators = new LinkedList<>();

List<UserGroupRole> allOrganizationAdministrators = 
    UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroupRolesByGroupAndRole(
        this.currentOrganization.getGroupId(), roleId);

for (UserGroupRole userGroupRoleTemp : allOrganizationAdministrators) {
    administrators.add(userGroupRoleTemp.getUser());
}
```

Cheers!